# Joining Dictionary key that matches class List's list item into a new list - C#

Tags: c#, linq, list, dictionary

So I have a `Dictionary`with string values as Keys. And I have a class List:

```
listCoord = new List<Coord>();
```

whose class `Coord` looks like:

```
class Coord
{
    public string Segment { get; set; }
    public double startX { get; set; }
    public double startY { get; set; }
    public double endX { get; set; }
    public double endY { get; set; }
}
```

And it has around 12000 `string Segment` 's. My Dictionary's `Keys` are among the some of those segments. Now I need to join the segments that are in my Dictionary with those coordinate values that are in the `List`.

At first I went with the approach to use `foreach` and go trough each dictionary key to compare it with the list segments to find the matches. Then I've learned that LINQ can use SQL's inner joints to do the same thing.

Questions:

1. What is the best way to find the matches between Dictionary Keys and certain list item?
2. Once I do, how do I put it all into another List that contains the matching `segment` and its corresponding `startX, startY, endX, endY` values as list items.?

I apologize in advance if such question has already been asked and answered; personally couldn't find it.

Comment: how your Dictionary looks like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also try this

```
    var listCoord = new List<Coord>();

    Dictionary<String, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dict.Add("A", "Myvalues");


    listCoord.Add(new Coord
    {
            Segment = "A",
    });

    listCoord.Add(new Coord
    {
      Segment = "B",
    });

    listCoord.Add(new Coord
    {
       Segment = "C",
    });

    List<Coord> result = listCoord.Where(cords => dict.ContainsKey(cords.Segment))
                         .ToList();
```

> Use `ContainsKey` and/or `ContainsValues` based on your requirement.

Sample working available at [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Qz5qml)

Thanks for the catch @Yacoub Massad

Comment: This worked. The last statement is the one that did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

This is the way to join List & Dictionary (you will get only matching Coords)

```
 List<CoordNew> newlist = listCoord .Join(strDictionary, 
                                 a => a.Segment, //From listCoord
                                 b => b.Key, //From strDictionary
                                 (a, b) => new CoordNew() { 
                                      Segment_dictionaryValue = b.Value
                                      //Other values from list or dictionary
                                 }).ToList();
```

If you need `CoordNew` as

```
class CoordNew
{
    public string Segment { get; set; }
    public string Segment_dictionaryValue { get; set; }
    public double startX { get; set; }
    public double startY { get; set; }
    public double endX { get; set; }
    public double endY { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Also confirmed this working, but I'll go with Eldho's answer, less code. Though I'll need this Join example in a different piece of code, so thank you :)

Comment: Thanks @Romy. There is a difference between my answer and @Eldho. The `result` in his solution is not giving you dictionary value of segment 'A'. However you may not need that, then follow the above (@Eldho's), which is short & perfect to filter a list.